# Android Fragment: Top of Content is Cut Off When Vertically Centered in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-scrollview, androidx

I'm trying to build an intro to my AndroidX app with a ViewPager and Fragments (similar to this [Intro Slider Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)) and have run into a layout problem.
I've got a Fragment in which I want the contents to be vertically centered. I've added a ScrollView as the root element of the Fragment in case the contents are too long to fit the screen.

If the contents aren't too long they are centered perfectly and nothing is cut off:
[centering working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxZ8s.png)

If they **are** too long though, the top of the content gets cut off and some extra space is added to the bottom (seems to be exactly the height of what was cut off the top):
[overlong content, title cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0XdK.png) 
[overlong content, additional space at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtGJJ.png)

---

### Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_view_fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/web_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/web_view_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/web_view_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/web_view" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Please note:**
Android Studio displays a warning for the ScrollView:

> **ScrollView size validation** 
>   This androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height attributes to wrap_content rather than fill_parent or match_parent in the scrolling dimension
>   Issue id: ScrollViewSize

However, changing the *layout_height* of the ScrollView to *wrap_content* **doesn't** fix the problem and an error is shown instead of the warning:

> **WebViews in wrap_content parents** 
>   Placing a  in a parent element that uses a wrap_content layout_height can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent instead
>   The WebView implementation has certain performance optimizations which will not work correctly if the parent view is using wrap_content rather than match_parent. This can lead to subtle UI bugs.
>   Issue id: WebViewLayout

---

### Activity layout with ViewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- intro_activity -->

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/intro_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blueGray700">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/intro_tab_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/intro_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/intro_continue_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/intro_skip_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intro_skip_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_skip_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="finishTutorial"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intro_continue_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="nextFragment"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_continue_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Clearly there's something wrong with my layouts but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**What I have found out so far:**

- The padding of the TextViews is not the problem.
- If I remove *android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"* from the ConstraintLayout nothing is cut off. But then my contents are obviously not centered (which I want for aesthetical reasons).

Comment: did you had a look at this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/ ?

Comment: Thanks @nimi0112, I did have a look at that but it's not quite the same seeing as the fragments aren't inside a ScrollView in the tutorial. The problem with my code **only** occurs when the content is too long to fit on the screen.

Comment: Why do you need fragments when you can do all your work within layout i.e by adding the scroll view in the layout file itself. I am using this in the live app and I am handling touch events as well. Let me know where do you need help

Comment: @nimi0112 I have several slides that the user can swipe through (very much like the intro slider in your link). I don't know of any other way to do this other than using Fragments. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: jus explain your use case via diagram or more and I can provide you an exact implementation.

Comment: please add screenshot and read this post [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972645/cut-off-items-at-the-bottom-of-the-fragment-page/56984203