# Cut off items at the bottom of the Fragment page

Tags: android

I have a Fragment page when my items are placed at the bottom of the page and half of them are cropped

[image]

this code `Fragment`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/Recycler"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginRight="10dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>-->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this code `Activity`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Fragment_Main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorCenteral"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think the issue is on your activity layout. Also, include it in your question.

Comment: enclose your parentLayout with a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please Add this code to **res>values>styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and edit **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

You must use `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar`